# Piecewise Function vs Regular Function

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm into graphing functions and I'm currently working on some project of mine. I'm a little confused, **what's the main distinction of a Piecewise Function with just a Regular / $f(x)$ Function?** I mean, most Piecewise functions posses the same format of equations with an $f(x)$ Function.

Comment: What is exactly don't you understand? A piecewise function is just a function which is made up of multiple functions and is defined by exactly one of them in every part of its domain.
f(x) is just the notation for a function. It can also be used for a piecewise function.

Comment: There are **piecewise continuous** functions and **piecewise smooth** functions etc. but **piecewise function** is a nonsense term which seems to have some popularity e.g. on this site. There is no need for the term because, as you say, a "piecewise function" is just a function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally a piece-wise function has at least one jump discontinuity in it. For example $F(x) =1$ is a "regular" function as you refer to it; whereas
$G(x)= \begin{cases} 
      -1 & x< 0 \\
      0 & 0\leq x\leq 100 \\
      1 & x > 100 
   \end{cases}$ is piece-wise (it has jump discontinuities at $x=0$ and $x=100$). For more info see the [Wikipedia article on piecewise functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise).